# Dynamically Generated AJAX/JS calculator form

Tags: javascript, forms, user-input, dynamic-data

I am trying to make a form that generates a value based on weighted inputs.  For example, if we had the following in the database

```
**Item**   _|_**Weight**
sink        | 1.5
toilet      | 2.5
shower      | 3
```

And a form that looked like this, built from the database, using AJAX (Has to be built using AJAX, because the inputs' names and the number of inputs varies depending on a user selection in a previous section of the form)

```
<form id="calculator">
...There are several field sets here...
    <fieldset id="myFields">
        <input type="text" class="iteminput" data-weight="1.5" name="sink" id="sink">
        <input type="text" class="iteminput" data-weight="2.5" name="toilet" id="toilet">
        <input type="text" class="iteminput" data-weight="3" name="shower" id="shower">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

If the user puts in that they have X sinks, Y toilets, and Z showers, I want to automatically calculate the total "value" of their plumbing system, in this case, X*1.5+Y*2.5+Z*3.

Where I am hung up is on how to get the value of each input.  What I want to be able to do is loop through all of the inputs in #myFields, get the value of the field, as well as the value of the data-weight attribute, multiply them together, then add them to a running total.  I would like to do all of this in a function attached to the onKeyUp event for each input.

Any help is appreciated, and more information can be provided if necessary.

Javascript only solution would be best, but I am not against using jQuery if it drastically simplifies the answer.

Comment: I ended up using a pure javascript approach.  I will post it once it is fully functional.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a jQuery example:**

You should be able to get the values of the inputs on a blur function. And then update the values by running an each function on the inputs. Something like this...

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Number of X</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="x"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Number of Y</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="y"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Number of Z</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="z"/>
    </li>
</ul>

<p>Total is: <span class="total"></span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input').blur(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('input').each(function() {
        total += Number($(this).val());
    });

    $('.total').text(total);
});
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/DYzsR/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.

```
function calcFixtures()
{
    var elements = [];
    var total = 0;
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName('fixtureinput');
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        total += elements[i].value * elements[i].getAttribute("data-weight");
    }
}
```

Logic being, get all elements with a certain class, loop through them, and for each element, get the value of the data-weight attribute and multiply it by the current form value for that element.  Thanks to @Kris for the idea of doing it as a running total rather than a single calculation.  That was really the breakthrough point.